# Javascript not running on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a JavaScript snippet that runs very well on Firefox and Safari, but refuses to run on IE:

```
var drop= function(id)
{
   if(document.getElementById("select1").value == "Ficha de pediatria"){
    top.location.href = "print.jsp?id="+id+"&type=2";
   }
   else if(document.getElementById("select1").value == "Ficha normal"){
        top.location.href = "print.jsp?id="+id+"&type=1";
   }
}

<select id="select1" name="select1" onChange="drop(id);return false;">
<option>Imprimir:</option>
<option>Ficha de pediatria</option>
<option>Ficha normal</option>
</select>
```

I trimed this as it had more JSP code but it' remained the same. Anyone got any idea why it's not running on IE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EDIT]  Sorry.  I introduced an error with my first post by not carefully looking at how you are constructing your url.  I shouldn't have removed the `id` parameter.  I've updated the code and it should work now.

Try this instead:

```
function drop(ctl,id)
{
   var value = ctl.options[ctl.selectedIndex].value;

   if(value == "Ficha de pediatria"){
       window.top.location.href = "print.jsp?id="+id+"&type=2";
   }
   else if (value == "Ficha normal"){
       window.top.location.href = "print.jsp?id="+id+"&type=1";
   }
}

<select id="select1" name="select1" onChange="drop(this,id);return false;">
<option>Imprimir:</option>
<option>Ficha de pediatria</option>
<option>Ficha normal</option>
</select>
```

[EDIT] A bit of explanation...

I think the issue is how it is accessing the DOM.  I don't think that IE has a value property on a select.  I think you have to get at it via the selected option.  Also, I'm not sure that there is a top property in the global namespace, but you should be able to get at it via `window.top` to set the location.  Finally, I made a slight improvement in that by specifying `this` as the argument, you can skip the element lookup and reference it directly from the control passed as the argument.

Comment: I think I fixed it -- I missed the use of id -- is this a global variable? -- so it should not have been removed from the function call.

Answer (score 3):

IE doesn't like the way you're grabbing the value of the select

```
document.getElementById("select1").value
```

This is saying "give me the text that's in the value attribute of the selected option in the select element with the id *select1*.  Your options don't have any values.  When Firefox and Safari encounter this ambiguity, they return the text of the selected option.  When Internet Explorer encounters this ambiguity, it returns a blank string.  Your javascript would work as is if you did something like

```
<select id="select1" name="select1" onChange="drop(this,id);return false;">
    <option value="Imprimir:">Imprimir:</option>
    <option value="Ficha de pediatria">Ficha de pediatria</option>
    <option value="Ficha normal">Ficha normal</option>
</select>
```

If that's not possible, you'll want to grab the *text* of the option that's selected.

```
var theSelect = document.getElementById("select1");
var theValue  = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].text
```

Finally, while not your direct question, a the hard coded *select1* isn't the best way to get at the select list.  Consider using the this keyword

```
function foo(theSelect){
    alert(theSelect.options);
}
```

...

```
<select id="whatever" onchange="foo(this);">
...
</select>
```

This is a bit more generic, and you'll be able to use your function on a select with any ID.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that IE "doesn't have .value" of a <select> element, it's that you **haven't specified any values for your <option> elements**.  Firefox, Safari, and co. are likely protecting you from this mistake.  Nevertheless, your element should be constructed as:

```
<select ...>
<option value="Imprimir">Imprimir:</option>
<option value="Ficha de pediatria">Ficha de pediatria</option>
<option value="Ficha normal">Ficha normal</option>
</select>
```

...and you'll see more standard x-browser behavior for the <select>'s .value property.

Answer (score -4):

I see two possible reasons.

**1** - The way the function is declared. I've never seen it like that though I guess it works.

Maybe try the following and see if it still does not work:

```
function drop(id)
{
    // same code
}
```

---

**2** - The return false in IE does not always behave properly (trust me, it depends on the computer) So instead of returning false, try:

```
onChange="drop(id);event.returnValue=false;return false;"
```

If possible create a method like this one:

```
function CrossBrowserFalse()
{
     if(IE) // use whatever you want to detect IE
     {
         event.returnValue = false;
     }

     return false;
}
```

and then in your methods you can use:

```
onChange="drop(id);return CrossBrowserFalse();"
```

...yeah, IE is weird sometimes (often)

---

If these two fail, at least make sure your drop function is called by putting some alerts in there or breakpoints if your IDE supports it for javascript.