# Simple JavaScript problem: onClick confirm not preventing default action

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple remove link with an onClick event that brings up a confirm dialog. I want to confirm that the user wants to delete an entry. However, it seems that when Cancel is clicked in the dialog, the default action (i.e. the href link) is still taking place, so the entry still gets deleted. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here... Any input would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Actually, the way the code is now, the page doesn't even make the function call... so, no dialog comes up at all. I did have the onClick code as:

```
onClick="confirm('Delete entry?')"
```

which did bring up a dialog, but was still going to the link on Cancel.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<script type="text/javascript">

function delete() {
    return confirm('Delete entry?')
}

</script>


...

<tr>
 <c:if test="${userIDRO}">
    <td>
        <a href="showSkill.htm?row=<c:out value="${skill.employeeSkillId}"/>" />
        <img src="images/edit.GIF" ALT="Edit this skill." border="1"/></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="showSkill.htm?row=<c:out value="${skill.employeeSkillId}&remove=1"/>" onClick="return delete()"/>
        <img src="images/remove.GIF" ALT="Remove this skill." border="1"/></a>
    </td>
 </c:if>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

There's a typo in your code (the tag **a** is closed too early).
You can either use:

```
<a href="whatever" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')"><img ...></a>
```

note the **return (confirm)**: the value returned by scripts in intrinsic evens decides whether the default browser action is run or not; in case you need to run a big piece of code you can of course call another function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_delete() {
  return confirm('are you sure?');
}
</script>
...
<a href="whatever" onclick="return confirm_delete()"><img ...></a>
```

(note that delete is a keyword)

For completeness: modern browsers also support DOM events, allowing you to register more than one handler for the same event on each object, access the details of the event, stop the propagation and much more; see [DOM Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_Events).

Comment: `onClick="return confirm('Are you absolutely sure you want to delete?')"`

Answer (score 33):

Well, I used to have the same problem and the problem got solved by adding the word "**return**" before confirm:

```
onclick="return confirm('Delete entry?')"
```

I wish this could be heplful for you..

Good Luck!

Comment: are you sure this works? It asked me for confirmation but even if Cancel selected link action is performed...

Comment: @Gediminas which OS/browser?

Comment: Sorry, some other code block was causing an error on this line. It works well in plain html example

Answer (score 12):

I use this, works like a charm. No need to have any functions, just inline with your link(s)

```
onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this comment?')"
```

Comment: There is also no need to use "javascript:". But like siukurnin said, you should use POST if you change something.

Answer (score 8):

I had issue alike (click on button, but after cancel clicked it still removes my object), so made this in such way, hope it helps someone in the future:

```
 $('.deleteObject').click(function () {
    var url = this.href;
    var confirmText = "Are you sure you want to delete this object?";
    if(confirm(confirmText)) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:url,
            success:function () {
            // Here goes something...
            },
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Using a simple link for an action such as removing a record looks dangerous to me : what if a crawler is trying to index your pages ?
It will ignore any javascript and follow every link, probably not a good thing.

You'd better use a form with method="POST".

And then you will have an event "OnSubmit" to do exactly what you want...

Comment: This is an excellent point.  Not only is it potentially dangerous to your application, it's actually a violation of the HTTP spec.

Comment: JW. Can a crawler access records without being able to login?

Comment: No, crawlers would not be able to access protected portions of your site.

Comment: It the "protection" depends on javascript, the crawler (and anyone who has turned of javascript) can access it.

Comment: @PeterBailey What part of the HTTP spec deals with this?  Can you add a link or something?  I am interested in reading about this further.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, **delete** is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words) in javascript, I'm surprised this even executes for you (When I test it in Firefox, I get a syntax error)

Secondly, your HTML looks weird - is there a reason you're closing the opening anchor tags with `/>` instead of just `>` ?

Comment: Wow, brain fart. Didn't think to check 'delete' as a keyword. Kind of a "duh" when so many other languages have it reserved. :P

Comment: XHTML uses /> to close empty tags... That means that the in the code from the original post, the a-tags are closed twice!!

Answer (score 4):

```
<img src="images/delete.png" onclick="return confirm_delete('Are you sure?')"> 



<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_delete(question) {

  if(confirm(question)){

     alert("Action to delete");

  }else{
    return false;  
  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use small inline commands in the onclick tag you could go with something like this.

`<button id="" class="delete" onclick="javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')){jQuery(this).parent().remove(); return false;}" type="button">
    Delete
</button>`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
OnClientClick='return (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"));'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning true from the delete() function, which tells the browser to follow the link even if the user clicks Cancel. To fix this, you need to return false from the function if the user clicks Cancel. Here is the updated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function delete() {
    var confirmation = confirm('Delete entry?');
    if (confirmation) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had issue with IE7 and returning false before.

Check my answer here to another problem: [Javascript not running on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257085/javascript-not-running-on-ie#257097)