# OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete');"

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using this code for confirmation on deletion. When I click on the link button, it asks me for confirmation, **but the first time I click OK, the record is not getting deleted (only for the first time)**.

**Thereafter that record gets deleted successfully.**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkBtnDelete" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete');" 
CommandName="Delete">Delete 
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify this statement? Are you saying it does not work the first time you click 'Ok' only the second time?

Comment: Does the page post-back, and the record isn't deleted? It could be a view state issue.

Comment: You must be using a UpdatePanel ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple JavaScript problem: onClick confirm not preventing default action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335516/simple-javascript-problem-onclick-confirm-not-preventing-default-action)

Comment: Have you debugged and verified that the delete command is being triggered?

Answer (score 30):

If the above answers doesn't workout for you then try below code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkBtnDelete" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) return false;" 
CommandName="Delete">Delete 
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this works and a simple `return confirm('Delete Record?');` won't?

Comment: @SBF: Because ASP.NET just "copy&paste"s the OnClientClick code into the middle of its own method. Thus, `A; return confirm(...); B;` *never* executes `B` (which contains the code required for calling the server-side method). However, `A; if (!confirm(...)) return; B;` does. Note that the return value of your custom code is irrelevant and a red herring.

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkBtnDelete" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete');" 
CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="">Delete 
</asp:LinkButton>
```

you must put CommandArgument so it will work from first time