# OnClientClick JavaScript Confirm is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have asp button, which functionality is for deleting the item. Button is inside the update panel. I have datalist in that I have adding the Item and with every time I have a checkbox. I have 2 button Select All and Clear All, I am selecting all the item with my Select All button that is JQuery Code after that I am trying to delete the time. when I am selecting the item one by one then its working fine, when selecting all items then its not working.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="Delete" 
           OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');$.loading({ mask: true, effect: 'ellipsis update' });" 
           OnClick="Button1_Click" />
       </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

HTML it is generating..

```
<div id="Tab1_UpdatePanel1">
      <input type="submit" id="Tab1_Button1" value="Delete Image" name="Tab1$Button1">
</div>
```

JQuery for Enabling disabling Button1

```
  $("#[id$='btnCheckAll']").click(function () {
     $("#<%= dlst1.ClientID %> input:checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
     $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled');
  });

  $("#[id$='btnUnCheck']").click(function () {
       $("#<%= dlst1.ClientID %> input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
       $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
```

and on page_load also I am making Button1.Enable=false; and when I am selecting any item I directly without using checkbox i am making Button.Enabled=true over there.

Button functionality is working fine but Confirm box is not showing, I checked this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335516/simple-javascript-problem-onclick-confirm-not-preventing-default-action) also but not working for me.

When I am making my button enable then its working fine, But I have the condition where I need to disable the button and based on some condition i am enabling the button. then its not working.

Please someone help me?

Comment: If client side JavaScript isn't working, why are you showing us only ASP? If the ASP not generating the HTML and JavaScript you expect? (If so, show us the HTML and JS and tell us how it differs from what you want). Does the HTML and JS not do what you expect? (In that case, don't show us the ASP at all).

Comment: If you could grab the html that ASP.NET is generating and post it up, it might be a bit more telling why this problem is occurring. Also, i'd try the same code you have shown without the UpdatePanel, as I suspect that is where the cause of your problem may originate.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, I'm wondering if the event code you specify for OnClientClick is being rendered in the onclick handler of the resultant HTML for the page...can you verify?

Comment: I copy your code and it works fine for me. confirm box was displayed and all was ok. I made only one change: I changed the: enable=false to true, but I guess that's not your problem....

Comment: I have added the HTML code also

Comment: I copied your code and it's working, either there is something missing in your code or something different between ours and yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try enbaling the button and then click on it.. it will surely work

Comment: how enable and disable will effect the javascript. Ur ans is working when i am enabling the button, But I have the condition when I need to disable the button, and on selecting the item it will get enable, in this case its not working

Comment: show us the code block where you are enabling the button, then we will be able to help you more better

Comment: instead of removing the disabled attribute, try changing it to `attr('disabled', 'enabled');`

Comment: what are the id's of the checkboxes!! try using the client id of the checkboxes too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you encounter the problem using jquery, try these alternative solutions:

1. simple javascript:

   ```
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete User" OnClientClick="return  confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');" />
   ```
2. Ajax ConfirmButtonExtender:

   ```
   <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server"
   TargetControlID="Button1"
   ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to click this?"
   OnClientCancel="CancelClick" />
   ```

Comment: yeah! there should not be any problem, if so, might be issue with :$.loading({ mask: true, effect: 'ellipsis update' });. That is why I have mentioned in my answer using simple javascript approach.