# ASP.NET checking radiobutton list values with javascript and then calling a c# method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This question is edited from original to better reflect what I am trying to accomplish.  I have taken out the errors I was getting before and restated the question based on the new logic I have come up with to resolve my previous problem which was no text would show in the pop up dialog that was called through c# but was a javascript method.  Here is the new question:

I have a radio button group as this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblMyGroup" runat="server" 
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How can I with c# check if the value "Yes" is selected.  Afterwards if the value yes is selected, how can I throw a popup message saying "Are you sure?".  If the user clicks yes it needs to run a method, if the user clicks cancel it should not do anything.  If the value no is selected, then the same method from yes option in c# should be called.

The c# method is called: `myAwesomeMethod(string s)` Once called it will change the text of the a button on the page.  Its that simple.  I have simplified the methods here to make the question better understandable.  If I can solve this,  I will be able to solve problems I am having.

Comment: This works for me. There might be something else messing up with the javascript.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to set this in the code-behind?

Comment: What browser are you testing this with?

Comment: What browser are you testing in?  Have you tested other browsers?

Comment: You don't have to use attribute and "onclick". Try `btn1.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are You Sure?')";`

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I tried it that way just now as well, and got the same thing.  I edited my question as well to give a better explanation

Comment: "return confirm('Are You Sure?');"...make sure semi is in the quotes...Also, are you creating this button dynamically in the code-behind? If so, you could be losing the button state. Try saving the button is in sesson and adding it back on the Init so its available on the onload.

Comment: @foxtrotZulu I edited my question to show you what I am doing now, but it is still the same result.

Comment: What is the HTML that gets rendered?

Comment: Also, try using the lower case version of "onclick".

Comment: lower case and upper case give me the same problem, now it is crashing and it wont even show the popup.  -- Can somebody give me a different approach to achieve this?

Comment: Post all your code please..

Comment: I have edited the question so that it reflects the new logic that I have come up with to bypass the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if it's what you want, but you have to say to the code what it will do when "Yes" is pressed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var r = confirm('Are you sure?');

        if(r == true)
        {
           alert("You pressed OK!")
        }
        else
        {
           alert("You pressed Cancel!")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Also, take a look at this question: [Simple JavaScript problem: onClick confirm not preventing default action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335516/simple-javascript-problem-onclick-confirm-not-preventing-default-action)

Comment: return is an undesireable variable name

Comment: that's true, forgot that

Comment: I tried this as well, but the problem here I have is that I don't know if user clicked ok or cancel.  I need to return the value true or false to be able to use it in my c#.  How can I call this method and get the value?

Comment: @Bagzli You can't get a Javascript value directly into your C# code-behind; by the time the browser sees the Javascript code, the code-behind has long since finished executing (simplifying slightly). You *could* look into AJAX or a repost of the form, but that's more involved.

Comment: You can do a post to server using ajax case r == true

Comment: @MichaelKjörling can I do the opposite, see the value in a radio button in a java script code?  I can do the validation that I need in the js as well and make it work.  Basically how would I say this:  If radio button selected value is yes show the dialog.  If dialog answer is yes, continue with code, if no stop.  -- or how would i call a c# method from JS?  Is that possible?

Comment: to check if a radio button is checked you can use: `$('#radio_button').is(':checked')` and it will return true or false

Comment: @Bagzli You can do a postback either to the same page or some other page from Javascript, which would trigger the whole ASP.NET code flow all over again allowing you to again do anything you want in the code-behind. That's a very different question though, and better asked by either editing this question or (preferably) simply asking a new one. It's too late for me to put together any code; someone else will probably be able to help you if you just put the question in a more visible form.

Comment: in javascript should be something like `document.getElementById('radio_button').checked`

Comment: Alright, I will change my question since we could not come up with a solution that works.