# How to useconfirm alert box in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take confirmation from the user after clicking the delete button.I'm facing issue user click on delete button alert box open if user click ok then record delete but click on cancel record delete why??

```
<a href="{{route('delete-engine-type',$value->id)}}" onclick="confirm('Are You Sure')"  class="btn btn-block btn-danger col action-btn js-del-btn" data-route="all-packages" data-model="package" data-id="">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple JavaScript problem: onClick confirm not preventing default action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335516/simple-javascript-problem-onclick-confirm-not-preventing-default-action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`confirm` returns true if Ok is pressed and false otherwise, so you should return the result of the function, as a false return value will prevent the default action.

```
onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure')"
```